# Template cast operator and boost::any or std::any

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-any

I wrote a generic class to provide an easy JSON-based init to any class.
It was working like a charm until I want to apply it to a class that contain an enum.

my base class first parse the JSON, find the sub object of the JSON that have the same `name` than the derived class (I use a CRTP ...), and build a `std::map<std::string, boost::any>  _settings;` where the key are the field name and the boost::any contain string, int, double and even array of number.

My derived class just need to implement an Update function like in the following example:

```
class testJsonUpdate : public JsonSettingsCustomizer<testJsonUpdate>
{
public:
  static const std::string class_name;

  testJsonUpdate(const std::string& settings) {
    _test_int = 0;
    _test_vector = { 0.0f };

    ParseAndUpdate(settings);
  }
  ~testJsonUpdate() {}

  int Update()
  {
    UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _test_int);
    UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _test_vector);

    return 0;
  }

public:
  uint32_t _test_int;
  std::vector<float> _test_vector;
};
const std::string testJsonUpdate::class_name = "testJsonUpdate";
```

The `UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _test_int);` is a MACRO and it's expansion use the following code.
The question is what can I do when my derived class has an emun member. **In that case, the boost::any value is an integer, and for now the call to the `explicit operator T()`with T = "MYCLASS::enum type" trigger an exception because of the boost::any_cast from int to my enum type !**

**is there a way to write a cast operator that boost::any cast use to solve that issue ?**

```
template<typename CALLER>
struct Value
{
std::string _key;
boost::any _value;

template<typename T>
explicit operator T() const
{
  try
  {
    return boost::any_cast<T>(_value); // <== where it trigger exception
  }
  catch (...)
  {
    throw std::logic_error(CALLER::class_name + ": config string parsing issue");
  }
}

template<typename T>
static Value<T> RetreiveValue(const std::map<std::string, boost::any> & settings, const   std::string & key)
{
  return{ key, settings.find(key)->second };
 } // RetreiveValue

#define UPDATE_VALUE(caller, member) \
key = BUILD_KEY(caller, member); \
if (_settings.end() != _settings.find(key)) \
{ \
   member = (decltype(member)) RetreiveValue<caller>(_settings, key); \
}
```

Full example to demonstrate the issue, tested on https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler with C++17 (to have the std::any support)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <any>


  template<typename CALLER>
  struct Value
  {
    std::string _key;
    std::any _value;

    template<typename T>
    explicit operator T() const
    {
      try
      {
        return std::any_cast<T>(_value);
      }
      catch (...)
      {
        //throw std::logic_error(CALLER::class_name + ": config string parsing issue");
        throw;
      }
    }
  }; // Value

  template<typename T>
  static Value<T> RetreiveValue(const std::map<std::string, std::any> & settings, const std::string & key)
  {
    return{ key, settings.find(key)->second };
  } // RetreiveValue

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  template <typename CALLER, typename T> const std::string buildPrefix(const T &elt)
  {
    throw std::logic_error(CALLER::class_name + ": config string parsing issue");
  } // buildName

  template <typename CALLER> const std::string buildPrefix(const bool &elt) { return "b"; }
  template <typename CALLER> const std::string buildPrefix(const std::string &elt) { return "s"; }
  template <typename CALLER> const std::string buildPrefix(const int &elt) { return "i"; }


#define ADD_M_PREFIX(member) m ## member

#define BUILD_KEY(caller, member) buildPrefix<caller>(member) + #member;
#define BUILD_KEY_WITH_M_PREFIX(caller, member) buildPrefix<caller>( ADD_M_PREFIX(member) ) + #member;
#define UPDATE_VALUE(caller, member) \
key = BUILD_KEY(caller, member); \
if (_settings.end() != _settings.find(key)) \
{ \
  member = (decltype(member)) RetreiveValue<caller>(_settings, key); \
}

#define UPDATE_VALUE_WITH_M_PREFIX(caller, member) \
key = BUILD_KEY_WITH_M_PREFIX(caller, member); \
if (_settings.end() != _settings.find(key)) \
{ \
  ADD_M_PREFIX(member) = (decltype(ADD_M_PREFIX(member))) RetreiveValue<caller>(_settings, key); \
}

  template<typename T>
  class JsonSettingsCustomizer {
  public:
    JsonSettingsCustomizer() : _label(T::class_name) { }
    virtual ~JsonSettingsCustomizer() {}

    int ParseAndUpdate(const std::string& settings) {
      //JSON Parsing to map

      //fake data to test
      _settings["i_integer"] = (int)(1);
      _settings["s_msg"] = (std::string)("hello world");
      _settings["i_enum_value"] = (int)(1);

      T& derived = static_cast<T&>(*this);
      auto ret = derived.Update();

      return ret;
    }

  protected:
    std::map<std::string, std::any>  _settings;
    std::string key;
    std::string _label;

  };
  /************************************************************************************************/
  //    END TOOLING
  /************************************************************************************************/

  typedef enum : int  {
     enum_one = 1,
     enum_two = 2
  } ENUM_TYPE;
//extention for the new ENUM_TYPE
template<typename CALLER> const std::string buildPrefix(const ENUM_TYPE& elt) { return "i"; }

class testJsonUpdate : public JsonSettingsCustomizer<testJsonUpdate>
  {
    public:
      static const std::string class_name;

      testJsonUpdate(const std::string& settings)  {
            ParseAndUpdate(settings);
      }
      ~testJsonUpdate() {}

      int Update()
      {
        UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _integer);
        UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _msg);
        //UPDATE_VALUE(testJsonUpdate, _enum_value); // uncomment to break on the bad cast exception

        return 0;
      }

    public:
      int _integer;
      std::string _msg;
      ENUM_TYPE _enum_value;
  };
  const std::string testJsonUpdate::class_name = "testJsonUpdate";

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    testJsonUpdate o(".... JSON .... ");
    std::cout << o._integer << std::endl;
    std::cout << o._msg << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with boost so I'll use the standard equivalent constructs. First question is: do you really want `any` or is `variant<string, int, ...>` a better choice?

Anyway, if you just want to wrap the cast you can do that easily:

```
template <typename T>
T json_cast(std::any const& val) 
{
    if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>)
    {
        return static_cast<T>(std::any_cast<int>(val));
    }
    else
    {
        return std::any_cast<T>(val);
    }
}
```

This requires that the `any` actually holds an `int`. You could also try `std::underlying_type_t<T>` instead of `int` but enums have some quirks with their underlying types so the cast could actually fail if the `any` holds an int.

C++14 version:

```
template <typename T>
T json_cast(std::any const& val) 
{    
    using cast_t = typename std::conditional<std::is_enum<T>::value, int, T>::type;
    return static_cast<T>(std::any_cast<cast_t>(val)); 
}
```

Comment: `if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>) ` will only work with C++17, is there a workaround to have the same with C++14 ?

Comment: Lot of  thanks ! I still have to try have across multiple compiler but all my target compiler have  C++14 so it should work, thank you again.

Comment: @alexbuisson my code is standard conformant, so as long as that compiler supports the C++14 standard you're good to go.